# Creating folder for all users

Tags: filesystem

I apologize for this novice question.
My PC is used by more people, each one with his own account.
I need to create some folders accessible to all the users to save common files and data.
Where is the right place to set it inside the file system?
How should I protect it so that all the users can read and write?
Regards
marius

Comment: The best practice would be to add all these users to a newly created group like `myusers` and create a folder like `/home/myusers` with permissions `rwxrwx---` and group ownerhip of `myusers` group (use `chown` command). Set also  the *setgid* bit on the directory `/home/myusers`.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli That should be posted as an answer :)